# What's the difference between fisher's Z and reliability&sample size adjusted r?

Tags: correlation, random-effects-model, meta-analysis, meta-regression

I am performing a meta analysis on random-effects model and I came across studies that compute r+ (sample size-adjusted correlation) and rc (reliability-adjusted correlation), and also those that compute fisher's z transformation.

I am using the metacor function from the meta package on r to do my analysis. In this case, should I adjust my r for sample size AND reliability before I transform them to fisher's z, or would fisher's z already have done that adjustment?

Answer (score 0):

Fisher's $z$ is defined as

$$
z = \frac{1}{2}\ln\frac{1+r}{1-r}
$$

There is no mention there of sample size nor of reliability coefficients.